# How to create FAB full screen transition

Tags: android, layout

I was seeing Materials.io website and I found out this animation:

[See this gif, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TuPq.jpg)

The problem is I can't find any code online that does this. How can I implement this the best way possible?

Answer (score 3):

Please try code given below

in your XML:

1. Add a property `android:transitionName="activity_trans"` in your FAB on FirstActivity

so your fab should look like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_one"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:src="@color/md_red_400"
        android:transitionName="activity_trans"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

2. In your SecondActivity layout add same property `android:transitionName="activity_trans"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/md_red_400"
        android:transitionName="activity_trans"
        tools:context=".SOF.SecondActivity">
    .
    .
    <!--    Your Other views goes here-->
    .
    .
</RelativeLayout>`
```

3. In your First Activity onClick of FAB

   ```
   fab_one = findViewById(R.id.fab_one);

   fab_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent prof_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);

           Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
           pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(fab_one,"activity_trans");


           ActivityOptions options ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, pairs);
           startActivity(prof_intent,options.toBundle());
       }
   });
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not produce the exact result shown in the GIF. WIth this code, the new activity starts out as a very shrunk rectangle atop the FAB. If you watch the GIF closely, the FAB changes from a circle and grows fullscreen to the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please see android developer page on transitions:
https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

Comment: But this doesn't add the transition that I showed in the gif ;)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was posted. The question is about the animation.

Comment: @GV_FiQst exactly ahah

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the required from the question.

Comment: I believe this page can help you: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity